# When I try to submit form without selecting date I have face undefined offset 1 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I click submit button without selecting date rage it gives me  `Undefined offset: 1`

I am selecting like this

```
public function create(){
    $bilty_date_range  =    $this->input->post('bilty_date_range');
    $temp = isset($bilty_date_range) ? $bilty_date_range : '00/00/0000 - 00/00/0000';
    $arr  = explode("-", $temp);
    $bilty_date_start = $arr[0];
    $bilty_date_end = $arr[1];
}


$data = array(
        'bilty_date_start' => date('y-m-d',strtotime($arr[0])),
        'bilty_date_end'        => date('y-m-d',strtotime($arr[1])),
        'bilty_range_from'      => $bilty_range_from,
        'bilty_range_to'        => $bilty_range_to,
    );
```

When I select date range record insert successfully

This the main Error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice Message: Undefined offset: 1 Filename: branch/BranchController.php
>
> Line Number: 153
>       Backtrace:
>       File: C:\xampp\htdocs.........................\BranchController.php
>       Line: 153   Function: _error_handler
>       File: C:\xampp.............\index.php
>       Line: 315  Function: require_once

Comment: maybe remove the javascript tag?

Comment: It would be useful to know which line is line 153 in this fragment which contains only 16 lines of code

Comment: It's not about tags plz give me some solution

Comment: Use `var_dump($temp)` and show us, please.

Comment: My guess si `$bilty_date_range` will always be set. So test `isset($this->input->post('bilty_date_range')` instead

Comment: I got this **string(0) ""** when **var_dump($temp)** is use @MorganFreeFarm

Comment: @ShaikhFarhanSultan check my answer

Comment: "It's not about tags plz give me some solution"
You tagged your question with `javascript` and it does not involve javascript.  If you're attracting the wrong attention, then it definitely is about tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$temp = isset($bilty_date_range) ? $bilty_date_range : '00/00/0000 - 00/00/0000';
```

Change this check, like this, because it can be empty:

```
$temp = (isset($bilty_date_range) && !empty($bilty_date_range)) ? $bilty_date_range : '00/00/0000 - 00/00/0000';
```

Or you can check why `$bilty_date_range` is empty.

More info [here](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/)

Comment: I use that code But still i get **1970-01-01 1970-01-01** I want **0** **0**